# Ionic cordova build fail

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've already added cordova-plugin-admob-free to my Ionic-Cordova project but when I try `ionic cordova run android` build fails with this message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKiB0.png)

I've tried with `multiDexEnabled true` but still the same problem.

Info:

```
Ionic-CLI: 3.19.1
Cordova: 7.1.0
Cordova-android: 6.4.0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try, First delete node_modules folder from your project.
the run npm install command again.